# Overriding $swipe internal method bind() events

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

So first I will tell my objective that I am trying to achieve. I have an hybrid app and the swipe action is not giving the feel of a native app. As in when you swipe in between the tabs in the native apps you can see the slide of the current tab going out and the new tab coming in. It is not very abrupt, and if you don't leave the touch in native apps you can be in a state where you see half of the first tab and half of the second tab.
(check the slide action in whatsApp tabs).

So right now I am using `ngTouch`'s `ngSwipeLeft` and `ngSwipeRight` where if I am adding any animation when the slide is done that is very abrupt and the ux is bad.

If you read through the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/service/$swipe) of `$swipe` then there are four events for a `swipe` action : `start`,`move`,`end` and `cancel`.
So how can I override these events so that I can add my custom css on the flow.

**So how can we get the swipe events to add functionality at that point.**

[image]

Comment: normaly it has to be very simple. use `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropgination` on your own listener functions to stop the default event.

Comment: @mtizziani But I want to just add my own css functionality at the invocation of those 4 events, not stop or anything as such. I just want to add something at that point of time when those events are invoked.

Comment: @arqum have you tried your css statements witch important statement? e.g. `.classOfSomething { color: red !important; }` this tells css to handle it stronger than inline statements. perhaps this helps you if you only want to manipulate the css functionality. otherwise you have to use js events that stop the original event until all things are done and call the original event then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So although I solved my problem in a different way, I would share how to override the `$swipe` `bind` methods.

So if say a directive `customizableswipe` is created, the the four methods can be `overriden` as follows :

```
angular.module('xpresso')
.directive('customizableswipe',['$swipe','$window',
  function($swipe,$window){

return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  link: function(scope,ele,attrs,ctrl){
    var startX,startY;

    $swipe.bind(ele,{
      'start' : function(coords){
        console.log("Coord start is :: ",coords.x);
      },
      'move' : function(coords){
        console.log("Coord move is :: ",coords.x);
      },
      'end' : function(coords){
        console.log("Coord end is :: ",coords.x);
      },
      'cancel' : function(coords){
        console.log("Coord cancel is :: ",coords.x);
      }
    });
  }
}
}]);
```

Hope this might help someone :)